# Regular expression detect that string contains both letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expression detect only letters+numbers not only numbers not only numbers

```
^(.*?(\b([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{7})\b)[^$]*)$
```

For example:

```
AB1234567 true
09AR30253 true
123456789 false
0912345JL true
AABBCCAAA false
```

Comment: I want to detect 2 characters and 7 numbers....

Comment: In this link not answer my question!!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to only match a string that has 2 *consecutive* letters in-between 7 digits? So, `1234RE567` is valid and `1234R5E67` is invalid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match 9 char strings that contain 2 consecutive letters and the rest is just digits, you may use

```
/^(?=.{9}$)\d*[a-zA-Z]{2}\d*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Lor3v/2/).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{9}$)` - the string length must be 9 chars
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `[a-zA-Z]{2}` - 2 letters
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['AB1234567', '09AR30253', '0912345JL', '123456789', 'AABBCCAAA'];
var rx = /^(?=.{9}$)\d*[a-zA-Z]{2}\d*$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```